# PHP Query error stdClass Object ( [Id] => )

Tags: php, salesforce

I'm executing this query on PHP:

```
$query = 'SELECT email__c, firstname__c FROM user__c'; 
$result = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

for($i = 0; $i < count($result->records); $i++) {
  print_r($result->records[$i])."<br/>\n"; 
  echo("<span>done</span><br/>\n");
}
```

I just have 2 elements in my database and the output is:

```
done
done
```

How I can print the values?

Comment: What is `var_dump` of `$result->records`?

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#14 (1) { ["Id"]=> NULL } [1]=> object(stdClass)#15 (1) { ["Id"]=> NULL } }` @u_mulder

Comment: Without knowing what `query` does in `$mySforceConnection`, I can't be sure, but it appears that your query method isn't creating the array properly.  Can you post that code, please.

Comment: You have an array containing two objects, each of which has an `Id` property, null. If the `Id` weren't null, you would be looking for `$result->records[0]->Id` or in a loop `foreach ($result->records as $record) { echo $record->Id; }` (incremental `for` loops are rarely used for iterating collections in PHP)

Comment: Based on your object name, I'm guessing that this has something to do with SalesForce?  If so, you might want to add that tag to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce returns an array of objects, try something like this instead:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    $i++;
    echo "\n".$i.": \n";
    print_r($record);
    echo "THE ID IS: ".$record->Id."\n";
}
```

Another point to remember with salesforce query results is if the field is empty they won't even return it in the object, so you may need to do something like this:

```
if (isset($record->Name)) { echo "The name is $record->Name\n"; } else { echo "name is blank\n"; }
```